# React select set initial value with Redux Form

Tags: reactjs, redux-form, react-select

I'm trying to set an initial value for my Select tag using Redux Form field.

Redux Field:

```
<Field
                    name="statusDto.pkid"
                    component={renderSelectField}
                    type="text"
                    isHidden="true"
                    placeholder="Select Status"
                    options={userRegistrationStatus && userRegistrationStatus.map((values) => { return ({ value: values.pkid, label: i18next.languages[0] === 'en' ? values.enName : values.trName }); })}
                  />
```

Redux Form:

```
UserRegistrationForm = reduxForm({
  validate,
  form: 'User_Registration_Form', // a unique identifier for this form
  enableReinitialize: true,
})(UserRegistrationForm));
```

React Select:

```
handleChange = (selectedOption) => {
    const { onChange } = this.props;
    this.setState({ selectedOptionState: selectedOption });
    onChange(selectedOption.value);
  };

 <Select
        name={name}
        value={selectedOptionState}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        styles={customStyles}
        options={options}
        clearable={false}
        className="react-select"
        placeholder={placeholder}
        isDisabled={isDisabled}
        classNamePrefix="react-select"
        theme={(theme) => ({
          ...theme,
          borderRadius: 0,
          colors: {
            ...theme.colors,
            primary: '#70bbfd',
          },
        })}
      />
```

Using redux-form initialize, I try to assign the first value to react-select but it doesn't seem to be worth it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.

React Select:

```
<Select
        name={name}
        value={(value === '') ? null : options.find(obj => obj.value === value)}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        styles={customStyles}
        options={options}
        clearable={false}
        className="react-select"
        placeholder={placeholder}
        isDisabled={isDisabled}
        classNamePrefix="react-select"
        theme={(theme) => ({
          ...theme,
          borderRadius: 0,
          colors: {
            ...theme.colors,
            primary: '#70bbfd',
          },
        })}
      />
```

Answer (score 0):

initialize redux **ReduxForm field** of you `Select` component with `{label:"LABELX", value: "ValueY"}`
on your `RenderSelectField` component add a property value that should be mapped to the property received from `props.input`

```
const RenderSelectField =(props) => {

  // Complete the seleect component with your additional props
  return (
    <Select
      value={props.input.value}
    />
  );
}
```

as the `value` is one element of your `options` array. you don't need to write a `find` function